# How to Check the Return Value of Class Based Component in React using Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

For example I have this **`Hook`** component:

```
const Color = ():JSX.Element => <div>Red</div>
```

But out of curiosity, how can I convert it to **`Class`** based component?

I know that I can have the `Props` and `State` like this

```
class Color extends React.Component<Props, State>{
   render(){ <div>Red</div>}
}
```

Is it possible to check the return value `JSX.Element` in the **`Class`** based component?

Comment: If you'd return something, Typescript could infer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the type of the `render` method on your `Color` class component like this: `Color["render"]`. And you can capture the return type with the built-in utility type `ReturnType<T extends (...args: any) => any>`. [Here's the full code in a TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=9&pc=48#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQLABQ9uANmugMIRPRxYAeMWAHYATdNjwwAdB3ARBQ+AG96cOJRFYocABQBKOMrqrVlGAFcoguAB5hwAG4A+awHo7TlXAC+9HwzowAJ5gWJhCwprY5pZwALxh0YIAKsFY1hxcUADaAETqEVA5ALqOQA).